# Removing outliers through averaging?

Tags: data-transformation, predictor

Is it okay to remove outliers by averaging the data set?

Say we have a response $Y$ for every day, **and $Y$ ITSELF is an average.**

Some days happen to give outlier responses. This makes analysis hard, but we do not really want to delete the outliers.

So, can we "average" them out?

---

For example, the data might be "average time per day spent eating".

Some days, there might be some outliers that we want to deal with before fitting the model.

So, we take two consecutive days, take the responses, and then average them. Then, the response is "average time spent eating for this two-day period".

Is this ok? If I do this, do I only do it for the outlier-responses, or do I transform all data like this?

Comment: Straight weighting with outliers creates bias. Robust methods typically downweight the extreme observations.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the data is an outlier then you should deal with it, e.g. remove it. Averaging is not a way to deal with outliers. Averaging works for noise reduction. Noise is not outliers. Your problem description sounds like if you were dealiong with noise, not outliers.

Example of an outlier: you're measuring the daily rainfall by checking the bucket outside your house. You collected the data but one day sticks out. You check the CCTV camera recording for that day and notice that a deer got into the backyard and kicked the bucket. The observation has obviously nothing to do with the rainfall, so you need to remove it.

This is very different from reading the small amount of rainfall from a big bucket. It'll be quite noisy, so you may want to average it out, to rolling weekly or monthly average. This is not an outlier, it's just the measurement noise.

These are two very different situations, and must be dealt differently.

Comment: Yeah, a critical distinction on outliers is whether they are driven by extreme behavior or error.

Comment: @MatthewGunn You are correct and statistics can not be used to tell the difference.

Comment: @MichaelChernick statistics is used to detect the outlier candidates. However, the final determination shouldn't be pure statistical

Comment: @Aksakal We are saying roughly the same thing.